# Can my characters age?

Tags: final-fantasy-tactics

Can I level up my characters without the game time affecting their age?

I'm asking that because before going into a new area, I level up my character skills. When they are strong enough, I go to a new area. The problem is the process takes a lot of in-game time.

So do my characters age? Can they die of old age?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In-game time has no effect on the story or characters in *Final Fantasy Tactics*. My sister got near 100 hours and was still in the first part of the game with no consequences.

Generally, unless the game clock is brought up as a real-time clock in the game's dialogue, you don't have to worry about things like that.

Answer (score 3):

**The characters in-game do not age, nor does the calendar affect the story.**

The in-game calendar is only used for two purposes. One is for Propositions you can do in the Bars found in various cities. Propositions are non-interactive side content which you can send up to three of your units to do, and require a number of in-game days to pass for completion.

The other purpose of the calendar is in monster breeding. The in-game date at which a monster egg hatches determines that monster's zodiac sign, as determined by the following table:

```
---------------------------------------------
 Sign         | Start Date   | End Date     |
---------------------------------------------
 Capricorn    | December 23  | January 19   |
 Aquarius     | January 20   | February 18  |
 Pisces       | February 19  | March 20     |
 Aries        | March 21     | April 19     |
 Taurus       | April 20     | May 20       |
 Gemini       | May 21       | June 21      |
 Cancer       | June 22      | July 22      |
 Leo          | July 23      | August 22    |
 Virgo        | August 23    | September 22 |
 Libra        | September 23 | October 23   |
 Scorpio      | October 24   | November 22  |
 Sagittarius  | November 23  | December 22  |
---------------------------------------------
```

Apparently, the in-game day being in a particular zodiac or on the birthday you select for Ramza has no effect on the game.

Source: http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps/197339-final-fantasy-tactics/faqs/23143